# How to get image from node

Tags: node-editor, image

Lets assume that i have a complex texture not just single image, it has  noise texture nodes i have a complex image output so here's the problem how do i get that complex image from nodes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're asking based on what you've written. Are you able to expand and/or add images to explain the problem?

Comment: i want to export the the image i mixed with nodes for my unity3d project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to **bake** the procedural texture into an image:

1. Add a plane into the scene, UV unwrap it and assign the procedural texture to it through emission shader (renders the fastest).
2. In UV/Image editor create a new texture of desired resolution.
3. Add texture node into the shader (unconnected but selected) and load the texture into it.
4. Bake the emission to the texture. Save texture as you desire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could apply your node(s) created texture to an evenly lit plane. Then set up a camera parallel to the plane and then render out an image file.